# how to search through associations in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get all profiles whom subject names will match with search keyword. right now i am loading all profiles. i need to know how do i achieve it. Any help is much appreciated.

**Profile.rb**

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :subjects, through: :categorizations
```

**Subject.rb**

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :profiles, through: :categorizations
```

**Categorization.rb**

```
belongs_to :profile
belongs_to :subject
```

**views/search/index.html.erb**

```
# search form
<%= form_tag search_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

# search results
<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <%= profile.name %>
<% end %>
```

**search_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.with_translations('en').all
end
```

Comment: Do you require the the search keyword match exactly the profile subject?

Comment: not exactly, if subject name has on word matching than still profile should display in search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something to add to this is the idea of [`full text searching`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) with Rails. If you're performing searches, you need to be aware that you're actually performing a full text "search" query in your DB, which is different depending on the SQL engine you use

---

**MYSQL Full Text Search**

The `LIKE %{search}%` mechanism is MYSQL's very basic full text search feature, and basically looks for your target query inside the whole record in your DB. This means that if your query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%alligator%'
```

MYSQL will basically look through the entire "name" record for any reference to your query. Results will be based on whether your record has the word "alligator" in any part of it. [This reference](http://devzone.zend.com/26/) explains some more about this

---

**PostgreSQL Full Text Search**

The reason I wrote this post is because PSQL actually does this differently, and therefore the query you have been provided will only work for MYSQL. PSQL has a lot of different functions to handle full text searching, but since we use Heroku, we managed to use the [Textacular gem](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) to get it all working properly

Here are [some ways PSQL handles full text searching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-MATCHING):

> Full text searching in PostgreSQL is based on the match operator @@,
>   which returns true if a tsvector (document) matches a tsquery (query).
>   It doesn't matter which data type is written first:

```
SELECT 'a fat cat sat on a mat and ate a fat rat'::tsvector @@ 'cat &
rat'::tsquery;  ?column?
----------  t

SELECT 'fat & cow'::tsquery @@ 'a fat cat sat on a mat and ate a fat
rat'::tsvector;  ?column?
----------  f
```

> As the above example suggests, a tsquery is not just raw text, any more than a tsvector > is. A tsquery contains search terms,
>   which must be already-normalized lexemes, and may combine multiple
>   terms using AND, OR, and NOT operators. (For details see Section
>   8.11.) There are functions to_tsquery and plainto_tsquery that are helpful in converting user-written text into a proper tsquery, for
>   example by normalizing words appearing in the text. Similarly,
>   to_tsvector is used to parse and normalize a document string. So in
>   practice a text search match would look more like this:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('fat cats ate fat rats') @@ to_tsquery('fat & rat');  ?column? 
----------  t Observe that this match would not succeed if written as
```

> SELECT 'fat cats ate fat rats'::tsvector @@ to_tsquery('fat & rat'); 
>   ?column? 
>   ----------  f

---

**Full Text Search Software**

Full text searching is inherently quite expensive on the DB, especially if you have a lot of data to search through. That's why solutions like [sunspot solr](http://sunspot.github.io/) or [sphinx](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx) exist -- to provide a way to both index & search the data you have

If your application becomes quite popular, you may wish to invest into one of the full text search systems, such as [these demonstrated by Heroku](https://addons.heroku.com/#search):

[image: Heroku's full text search packages]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer but actually i am new to rails and trying to understand how do i search through associations but i have found your answer as good option and let me try it on a new  application. i am trying with sunspot by seeing Ryan's railscast.

Comment: No problem! If you're new to rails, I would not actually recommend implementing the "hardcore" full text search stuff yet (it takes some work to get it working). What I wanted to do was give you a definition of what you're actually trying to do; instead of you just getting a query, you'll have a feature-set ready to implement when you polish your skills :)

Comment: After a few days practice i am successfully using Sunspot gem. Thanks to you for guidance. i have one question, can i use sunspot with globalize gem?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can use both gems together - why don't you ask a new question? :)

Comment: here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646808/how-to-add-translations-of-globalize-and-sunspot-solr

Answer (score 4):

```
@profiles = Subject.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").map(&:profiles)
```

Comment: i get following result "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'profile_id' in 'field list': SELECT profile_id FROM `subjects` WHERE (name LIKE '%%')"

Comment: now i am getting "undefined method `model_name' for" and it doesnt print profile.name in results.

Answer (score 3):

Check if this works.

```
@profiles = Profile.joins(:subjects).where("subject.name like '%?%'",params[:search])
```

Comment: No, its not working and give me following error"Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%''%)' at line 1: SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` INNER JOIN `categorizations` ON `categorizations`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` INNER JOIN `subjects` ON `subjects`.`id` = `categorizations`.`subject_id` WHERE (subject.name like %''%)"

Comment: @Murtza Edited. Also replace `params[:search]` with your search query

Comment: i replaced with a keyword "maths" but it still shows same error.

Comment: "maths" is available in subjects and there is a profile which selected "maths"

Comment: Can you post the query you executed

Comment: here is the url http://localhost:3000/en/search/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=maths

Comment: @profiles = Profile.joins(:subjects).where("subject.name like '%?%'","maths")

Comment: can u plz review the code in views/search/index.html.erb because may be i am making some mistake there because i cant print profile names and still is the same error.

Comment: @Murtza the link you provided is your local host. I cant view it. Please post the related files in question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39833/discussion-between-shiva-and-murtza)