# How to use globalize and sunspot in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

How do i index arabic profile translations with sunspot solr. Can i use globalize and sunspot or should use some other approach?

**models/profile.rb**

```
translates :name, :description
validates :name
validates :description

searchable do
  text :name
  text :description
end
```

Comment: why did you delete your jquery question? i was typing up an answer for it. I give everyone that speech about making an attempt, but i was still going to help you. if you repost the question, i have an answer ready for you

Comment: actually i have 2 down votes and i don't want to get blocked :( anyways i undeleted that question and you can write your answer.

Comment: if you edit the question i can remove my down vote.. it was my fault for assuming you were yet another SO leech who doesn't contribute, but looking at your profile you are quite active here. i'm going to post my answer, and if it doesn't work please comment i will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define separate fields for each of your locales in your search block:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  # Separate name field for each locale
  text "name_#{locale}".to_sym do
    # read_Attribute is defined by Globalize.
    read_attribute(:name, locale: locale)
  end
  text "description_#{locale}".to_sym do
    read_attribute(:description, locale: locale)
  end
end
```

When you are doing a search, you have to specify which locale you want to use:

```
# Search by actual locale
search = Sunspot.search(Profile) do
  fulltext "search term" do
    fields "name_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym,
           "description_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym,
  end
end
```